# Insert data from 5 spreadsheets into sql using a txt file output

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert information from 5 different spreadsheets into a MySQL table called *dosage* and need to output the SQL statement as a text document for actually inserting the information for later use. So far I have separated the different rows within each spreadsheet and appended them together and written code similar to this:

```
    for row in firstName:
        print(row)
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO dosage (a) VALUES (%s)" % row)
        db.commit()

    for row in lastName:
        print(row)
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO dosage (b) VALUES (%s)" % row)
        db.commit()

    for row in email:
        print(row)
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO dosage (c) VALUES (%s)" % row)
        db.commit()
```

I'm not entirely sure where to go from here to get this to be a text output for an SQL query.

I have 21 different rows, so any suggestions on consolidating would be awesome as well.

Comment: start with posting a table and data so we can see how the three columns are related.

Comment: Zip the values together: `for f_name, l_name, eml in zip(firstName, lastName, email):`. Note that you should not use string formatting for passing values to queries, but instead leave it to your driver, using placeholders in the query and passing the values to `execute()` separately. Producing SQL statements for inserting the information (later, to some other DB?) should be left to the DBMS' tools, such mysqldump.